# Quelle est la différence entre formation et diplôme ?

Tags: université

Quand je recherche les programmes de Master d'universités françaises, je trouve des programmes de Master différents.

Par exemple, il y a « diplômes », « formations délocalisées niveau Licence », « formations délocalisées niveau Master 1 », « formations délocalisées niveau Master 1 », « formation niveau Licence 1, 2 ou 3 ».

Quelle est la différence entre une formation et un diplôme ?

Answer (score 1):

Les deux sont liés.

Une formation, c'est le contenu des cours, ce qui permet aux étudiants d'acquérir des connaissances, des méthodes, etc.

Le diplôme, c'est un titre reconnu, délivré ici par l'université et que l'on obtient si on a réussi sa formation, donc à priori un Master.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!